# How to insert Image to or wepage from our own pc

Tags: html, image

I want to add image to my webpage using html and that image is already present in my computer in my C drive
i tried to copy the path and put it inside src but it didn't worked out i also tried to change the "/" to "/" but still nothing changed so kindly help me in adding image

Comment: Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to keep your project files in one folder. so its easier to link them.
now, create a folder and save your html file there.
then copy your image in the same folder.
now, use ***img*** tag to import a picture.
inside ***src*** attribute, type your image name with format(.jpg or .png or etc)

```
<body>
<img src="logo.jpg">
</body>
```

if you want to use an image from a folder inside your project folder, code like this:

```
<body>
<img src="folder/logo.jpg">
</body>
```